# Transferring a Readable Stream from one browser tab to another in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

I have looked into a few approaches to transfer a readable stream from one tab in Chrome to another:

1. Broadcast channel -- doesn't support transferrable objects in postMessage
2. Sender window postMessages to a Shared Worker connected to the sender and receiver windows. Shared Worker then postMessages to the receiver window.

From all of the documentation I have read, option 2 should work. However, my proof of concept fails with "DOMException: chunk could not be cloned" when I try to call the [`pipeTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/pipeTo) method on the readable stream received by the receiver window.

I suspect this is because there is an issue transferring a stream's data through an intermediary (the Shared Worker) to a final destination. When I perform the same steps below with an empty, `new ReadableStream()`, there is no DOMException, which leads to the conclusion that the process of transferring data in the stream is the source of the error. I am not sure if there is a way around this. I can't transform the readable stream within the shared worker because that will lock it, and locked streams cannot be transferred.

Note that my example uses a media stream to generate data on the readable stream. My particular use case is related to transferring audio between same-origin tabs, however I am trying to make this question generic to maximize its utility to others. Also, I am aware that [MediaStreamTracks are now transferable via a new w3c standard](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-extensions/pull/24), but no browsers support this as far as I am aware.

Example code:

```
//client.js
var myWorker = new SharedWorker("worker.js");
myWorker.port.onmessage = async (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    if (e.data === 'Trigger Transfer') {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true})
            .then(function(stream) {
                const audioTrack = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
                const trackProcessor = new MediaStreamTrackProcessor({ track: audioTrack });
                const readable = trackProcessor.readable;
                console.log("here");
                myWorker.port.postMessage(readable, [readable]);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log("Failed to get user media", err);
            });
    }
    else {
            if (e.data instanceof ReadableStream) {
            try {
                console.log(e.data.locked === false); //This prints true. Locking does not appear to be the problem.
                await e.data.pipeTo(new WritableStream()); //This line leads to "DOMException: chunk could not be cloned"
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

```
//shared-worker.js
onconnect = function(e) {
  var port = e.ports[0];
  setTimeout(()=>{
    port.postMessage("Trigger Transfer");
  }, 500);
  port.onmessage = function(e) {
    port.postMessage(e.data, [e.data]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you happen to make any progress on this? 